# Array elements (after using compound assignment operator) yields garbage value, why?

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, compound-assignment

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(void)
{
    int a[5]={90,78,77,98,98}, b[5]={80,45,67,88,57}, c[5]={88,99,65,55,74},total[3],i,j;
    for(j=0;j<=4;j++)
        {
            total[0]+=a[j];
            total[1]+=b[j];
            total[2]+=c[j];
        }

    for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
    {
    printf("%d행의 가로 합 : %d\n",i,total[i-1]);
    }
}
```

`total[0]` and `total[1]` are right value, but `total[2]` is wrong value. I cannot find my fault. Can you explain it?

Comment: What are the "wrong values" you are getting and what are you expecting?

Comment: Hint: 1. What are the initial values of `total`? 2. Can question 1 be answered?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first problem here is in the code

```
        total[0]+=a[j];
        total[1]+=b[j];
        total[2]+=c[j];
```

where you're using `total[n]`s un-initialized. They contain indeterminate values and using them invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To elaborate, `total` being an uninitialized automatic local variable, the initial values of the elements of the array are indeterminate. By using the `+=` operator on those elements, you're trying to *read* (use) the values which are indeterminate, so it invokes UB in your case.

Related quote from `C11`, chapter §6.5.16.2, *Compound assignment*,

> A compound assignment of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to the simple assignment
>   expression `E1 = E1 op (E2)`, except that the lvalue `E1` is evaluated only once, and with
>   respect to an indeterminately-sequenced function call, the operation of a compound assignment is a single evaluation. If `E1` has an atomic type, compound assignment is a
>   `read-modify-write` operation with `memory_order_seq_cst` memory order
>   semantics.

So, by using the `+=` on an uniniitilized value, _you're trying to read (*or use*) a variable with indeterminate value, which causes the UB.

If you want, you can initialize the whole array by using a syntax like

```
  int total[3] = {0};
```

which initializes *all* elements of the array to 0, which is what basically you were expecting.

That said, `void main(void)` is not a conforming signature for `main()` in a hosted environment, as per the spec, it should be `int main(void)`, at least.